# Serializing a collection and comply to Code Analysis

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, .net-4.5, code-analysis

While running Code Analysis on an existing project I came across the messages *Do not expose generic lists* and *Collection properties should be read only*.
However, this class is used to read/write from/to an xml configuration file.
Is it possible to make this class comply to [CA1002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx) and [CA2227](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx) or do I have to suppress these rules for XML-related classes (there are a lot of them in the project)?

**EDIT**

Changing `List<string>` to `Collection<string>` solved CA1002.
Still no clue on how to solve CA2227 and still be able to (de)serialize the whole thing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Class containing the Configuration Storage
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot("Configuration")]
public class ConfigurationStorage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the list of executers.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray("Executers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Executer")]
    public Collection<string> Executers { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the list of IPG prefixes.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray("IpgPrefixes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("IpgPrefix")]
    public Collection<string> IpgPrefixes { get; set; }

}
```

Reading the xml-file:

```
    public static ConfigurationStorage LoadConfiguration()
    {
        if (File.Exists(ConfigFile))
        {
            try
            {
                using (TextReader r = new StreamReader(ConfigFile))
                {
                    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationStorage));
                    var config = (ConfigurationStorage)s.Deserialize(r);
                    return config;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperationException)
            {
                throw new StorageException(
                    "An error occurred while deserializing the configuration XML file.", invalidOperationException);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exposing `Collection<T>` instead of `List<T>` side steps the warning but makes your code smellier. The warning is telling you to expose `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or maybe `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. However, as you've noticed, the standard `XMLSerializer` is not very flexible. I'd prefer code that works without the `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`, `Collection` is the only type you are using in that namespace.

Comment: @Jodrell I agree, but my hands are a littlebit tied here. Now at least my boss is happy because the warning is gone ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class containing the Configuration Storage
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot("Configuration")]
public class ConfigurationStorage {
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the list of executers.
  /// </summary>
  [XmlArray("Executers")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Executer")]
  public Collection<string> Executers { get; private set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the list of IPG prefixes.
  /// </summary>
  [XmlArray("IpgPrefixes")]
  [XmlArrayItem("IpgPrefix")]
  public Collection<string> IpgPrefixes { get; private set; }

  public ConfigurationStorage() {
    Executers = new Collection<string>();
    IpgPrefixes = new Collection<string>();
  }
}
```

This will still work for xml serialization/deserialization.

Comment: I don't think it will deserialize. How can the `XmlSerializer` set a private property?

Comment: This works indeed. I was under the impression that both getter and setter had to be public. See MSDN: _XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public properties and fields to a serial format (in this case, XML) for storage or transport. Deserialization re-creates the object in its original state from the XML output._

Comment: @Jodrell I've just tested it here and I was able to read the xml and add an element to it.

Comment: Right at the bottom of your rule - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx Both binary and XML serialization support read-only properties that are collections. The System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer class has specific requirements for types that implement ICollection and System.Collections.IEnumerable in order to be serializable.

Comment: @Koen I guess it works because `Collection` implements `ICollection`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.aspx), you see a note:

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that implement
>   IEnumerable or ICollection. A class that implements IEnumerable must
>   implement a public Add method that takes a single parameter. The Add
>   method's parameter must be of the same type as is returned from the
>   Current property on the value returned from GetEnumerator, or one of
>   that type's bases. A class that implements ICollection (such as
>   CollectionBase) in addition to IEnumerable must have a public Item
>   indexed property (indexer in C#) that takes an integer, and it must
>   have a public Count property of type integer. The parameter to the Add
>   method must be the same type as is returned from the Item property, or
>   one of that type's bases. For classes that implement ICollection,
>   values to be serialized are retrieved from the indexed Item property,
>   not by calling GetEnumerator.

So, I think, if you fall in line with this special treatment, you'll have better code that works with `XmlSerializer`, doesn't use a legacy namespace, and satisfies Code Analysis warnings in the right way, rather than exploiting an oversight in the rule.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Class containing the Configuration Storage
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot("Configuration")]
public class ConfigurationStorage
{
    // The executers.
    private readonly ICollection<string> executers = new List<string>();

    // The IPG prefixes.
    private readonly ICollection<string> ipgPrefixes = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of executers.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray("Executers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Executer")]
    public ICollection<string> Executers
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.executers;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of IPG prefixes.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray("IpgPrefixes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("IpgPrefix")]
    public ICollection<string> IpgPrefixes
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.ipgPrefixes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but the configuration is not read. No exception is thrown but the list of executers stays empty. When I change the type back to `Collection`, it's deserialized just fine.

Comment: Did some extra diging and it turns out you can't serialize an interface. So I guess I'm stuck with using `Collection<string>` here...

Comment: @Koen, I fear you are correct. You could do custom serialization, or implement `ICollection` on your own class. Both of which you could view as overkill.

Comment: Indeed. But since I'm a bit under time pressure here, I'll stick with the Collection. Thanks for your time.